# Navigating a webpage from hyperlink in different project but same asp.net solution

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am facing the following problem and its driving me crazy!

I have the following solution structure:

```
 Solution1
   project1
     page1.aspx
   project2
      page2.aspx
```

page1.aspx contains an asp.net menu control , i need to navigate from menuitem to page2.aspx which is in project2

In other words how can i access resources of a project from another project in the same solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the navigation already set up and you need to be able to debug `project2` but code starts running from `project1`?

Comment: not debugging the code. i need to set Navigation url property of menu item of a different project webpage in same solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 web projects in solution, that means you have 2 different web applications altogether. The only way you can navigate from a menu in one application to another, is simply by creating a link. Example:

Assuming:

Page1.aspx (in project1) is located in `http://localhost/App1/page1.aspx`

Page2.aspx (in project 2) is located in `http://localhost/App2/page2.aspx`

You can create a link in the menu in page1.aspx to page2.aspx by having link in the menu that points to: `http://localhost/App2/page2.aspx`

In other words, your menu has to have an element that reads this:

```
<a href="htp://localhost/App2/page2.aspx">Take me to page2 </a>
```

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Thanks.I tried with menu item
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Default2" Value="Default2" NavigateUrl="htp://localhost/Project2/Default2.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug Project2 but the starting point is Project1 - go to Project2 properties and point it Start URL to Project1:

[image]

Then compile and run Project2. It will start Project1 but when it redirects to Project2 you will be able to debug, use breakpoints etc.